# Python ImportError when executing through windows scheduler

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, windows-task-scheduler

I did some searches for this topic and found some prior threads, but I did not understand any of them as I am still a total beginner in Python.

I have a Python script which has some long string variables stored in various .py files in a sub-directory. I'm importing the .py files from that sub-directory when I run the script. There is a `__init__.py` file in the sub-directory. The only reason I'm using this setup is that the long string variables which I'm storing in those other files would make the code very difficult to read as they are SQL strings and can span 50-100 lines each.

Everything works perfectly when I run this script through PyCharm.

However, when I run the script through Windows Scheduler or a batch file, I get an ImportError for all of the .py files in the sub-directory. The problem is definitely related to the python script not knowing where to look for those .py files when it's run through Windows Scheduler. But I'm not sure how to fix it.

The action for the scheduler task is to run the python exe

```
D:\Python35\python.exe
```

with the argument as the script

```
D:\python\tableaudatasourcebuilds\dcitechnicalperformance\dcitechnicalperformance0.py
```

So the full action looks like:

```
D:\Python35\python.exe "D:\python\tableaudatasourcebuilds\dcitechnicalperformance\dcitechnicalperformance0.py"
```

The subdirectory which stores the long string variables .py files is:

```
D:\python\tableaudatasourcebuilds\dcitechnicalperformance\dcitechnicalperformance0\
```

The imports look like:

```
from dcitechnicalperformance.dcitechnicalperformance0.dciquer import nzsqldciwk
```

Does anyone know how to address this problem? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good afternoon,

First of all i don't know how much sense there is to store long SQL querys on a module, I'm not by any means an expert, but something like a **JSON file** (or hell, even store them in a table inside the sql) seems like a better approach.

About your problem I think it resides on the current directory where the task is launched, let me explain:

- In PyCharm when you run the code it launches **from the location of the file**, and with so, it's able to find the directory with the module.
- With the scheduled task it may be launching in another directory and so, it's unable to find the module as the directory is not present.

If you decide to stick with your reproach a plausible solution would be to create a .bat file that browses to the project location:

```
@ECHO OFF 
D:
cd D:\python\tableaudatasourcebuilds\dcitechnicalperformance\
D:\Python35\python.exe dcitechnicalperformance0.py
```

And that should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not work for me. I still received an import error. The way I solved is by storing the queries as text, and executing the text files as code. Still probably not the optimal solution, but at least it works.